# Making an array of Objects and using overloaded [] in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, operator-keyword

I created this class, say, `Apple`, and it has an overloaded `operator []`.
Then in another class, I made an array of apples, `Apple stack[10]`.
Then when I was using `stack[2]` in an expression, instead of `stack[2]` being an object, the compiler is acting like it sees stack as `stack[0]`, and then calling the `operator []` and its parameter as `2`.

Could you suggest a way I could calling `stack[2]` without being that way?

Comment: That seems weird; `stack[2]` should indeed give you the third `Apple` object. You should post your code - preferably, a simplified version that only includes the code that is necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: oh, ok, that was another problem. The reason I did not post it is because it's a school assignment, and pretty big assignment basing on prevoius assignments we built upon. Thanks for the big offer for help :D

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pointer to get array elements:

```
*(stack+2)[3]; // lookup element 2 and call its [] operator with 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information given so far, `stack[2]` refers to an `Apple` object. You can also do `stack[2][5]` to call the overloaded `operator[]` in your `Apple` class.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the code would have been helpful.

However, suppose you have a variable `x` in the class Apple. You can access it using `(stack+2)->x`. This would work same as `stack[2].x`. And in case you want to use your overloaded operator, you may use it similarly. This wont confuse the compiler.